# UICollectionView into UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to add `UICollectionView` into `UICollectionViewCell`. It seems easy but I don't get it.

I don't get to know where I have to initialize `UICollectionView` for each `UICollectionViewCell` and where to program `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` of each `UICollectionView`.

The result would be a collection of products (first `collectionview` where each cell is a product) and a collection of images for each product like image gallery (second collection view where each cell is an image). It's the same as **Zara app**.

First collection view looks like this and have only vertical scroll.

[image]

When you select a product, cells change their size to full screen size and the collection view change vertical scrolling to horizontal scrolling. Now vertical scrolling is for the second collection view, the image gallery.

Second collection view looks like this

[image]

In *storyboard* I have `UICollectionViewController` with `UICollectionViewDataSource`, `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` implementations.

**ProductsCollectionViewController.h**

```
@interface ProductsCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController &lt;UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout&gt; {
    NSMutableArray *products;
}
```

**ProductsCollectionViewController.m**

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return products.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"ProductCell";

    ProductCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Product *product = [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setProduct:product];

    return cell;
}
```

Product is a main `NSObject` that have some information and also an `array` of images.

**Product.h**

```
@interface Product : NSObject

@property NSInteger categoryID;
@property NSInteger productID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;
```

I think that what I have to do is create new `UICollectionView` programatically in each `ProductCollectionViewCell` with the `array` of images of the product but `ProductCollectionViewCell` don't recognize `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` and their implementation.

Comment: Hmm... seems like you're making it over complicated. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve? Also are you using the storyboard or setting up everything programmatically?

Comment: I need to do something like this http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell but with UICollectionViewController instead of UITableViewController. If you need I can put some code to clarify.

Comment: "but ProductCollectionViewCell don't recognize UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate and their implementation" – can you elaborate a little more on what you mean? Your approach should be working.

Comment: the second view looks to be a page view controller and not a collection view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start by having a `mainCollectionView`. Then on each cell of this collection create and initialize a new `UICollectionView` and right place to do that is in this following delegate of UICollectionView

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

e.g I initialize the `MainCollectionViewCell` here and then `MainCollectionViewCell` handles the logic to create a new `UICollectionView`

```
guard let collectionViewCell = cell as? MainCollectionViewCell else { return }

    collectionViewCell.delegate = self

    let dataProvider = ChildCollectionViewDataSource()
    dataProvider.data = data[indexPath.row] as NSArray

    let delegate = ChildCollectionViewDelegate()

    collectionViewCell.initializeCollectionViewWithDataSource(dataProvider, delegate: delegate, forRow: indexPath.row)

    collectionViewCell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0
```

Here is the initializer on `MainCollectionViewCell` that creates a new `UICollectionView`

```
func initializeCollectionViewWithDataSource<D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource>,E: protocol<UICollectionViewDelegate>>(dataSource: D, delegate :E, forRow row: Int) {

    self.collectionViewDataSource = dataSource

    self.collectionViewDelegate = delegate

    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseChildCollectionViewCellIdentifier)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionView.dataSource = self.collectionViewDataSource
    collectionView.delegate = self.collectionViewDelegate
    collectionView.tag = row

    self.addSubview(collectionView)

    self.collectionView = collectionView

    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope that helps !!

I did an example for this and put in on github. It demonstrates the use `UICollectionView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`.

https://github.com/irfanlone/Collection-View-in-a-collection-view-cell

Answer (score 0):

Using StoryBoard is possible too.

Inspired in [Ash Furrow's article](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/)

The main trick is in "willDisplayCell" method. Just make sure you are using the correct UICollectionViewCell class.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(PNCollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[PNCollectionViewCell class]]) {

        [cell setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:self indexPath:indexPath];
        NSInteger index = cell.collectionView.indexPath.row;

        CGFloat horizontalOffset = [self.contentOffsetDictionary[[@(index) stringValue]] floatValue];
        [cell.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(horizontalOffset, 0)];
    }

}
```

For more details you can see my sample on:
 https://github.com/pnovales/UICollectionViewInUICollectionViewCell